# "for..of" javascript return all value but return a extra index of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my code

```
function consec(string) {
  for (let letter of string) {
    console.log(letter);
  }
}

console.log(consec("zoo"));
```

the result is

```
"z"
"o"
"o"
undefined
```

This is the [link](https://codepen.io/NanJ90/pen/mXRoPw?editors=1111#) of my code. Please feel free to correct. (It's my first to ask question through SO, I appreciate any advices :))

Comment: Last `undefined` is the return value of `consec()` function. Since you are not returing anything from `consec()`, it is displaying `undefined`.

Comment: `undefined`here is the return value from the function. The characters are logged in the function, and "undefined" is logged from the `.log` which calls `consec` because the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `console.log()` from `console.log(consec("zoo"));` then you will not get that `undefined` printed in console as the last `undefined` is from the return value of `consec("zoo");` which is `undefined`.

```js
function consec(string) {
  for (let letter of string) {
    console.log(letter);
  }
}

consec("zoo");
```

Let's say if you have return value in function then you get that in console like this:

```js
function consec(string) {
  for (let letter of string) {
    console.log(letter);
  }
  return("Finished");
}

console.log(consec("zoo"));
```